# In core data, is there only one Managed Object in a MOC?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Here's a basic core data question: **in core data, is there only one Managed Object in a MOC?**

The documentation contains a nice graphic, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-207483-BCIEHJBA), that unfortunately confuses me (further). In the `NSManagedObjectContext`, it seems that there are multiple objects (Employees and Departments), and that each has multiple instances ("Jo", "Sales", etc). Yet in the section about "Managed Objects", [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html), it says: "*In a given context, for a given record in a persistent store, there can be only one corresponding managed object*".

Could someone explain the differences to between a Managed Object, a Managed Object Context, and a data record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple managed objects in a managed object context. You can think of a managed object context something like a transaction.

What the second bit of text is saying that every managed object maps to a single record in the persistent store (disk representation). So you could have multiple managed object contexts, each with a copy of a managed object context, yet they'd all map to the same record on disk.

Comment: Ah ok. Now, why would I want more than one managed object context? After all, I could put all my managed objects in that one context.

Comment: ...and a record is basically a file? If more records can be in one file, then why make the difference between a MOC and a record?

Comment: You would (typically) have one managed object context per thread.

Comment: No, a record would be the managed object. In database terminology: an Entity is a table; a managed object is a row or record; a managed object context is a transaction; and managed object model is a database schema. Having said that, it's best not to think of Core Data in terms of records, etc. It's a persistent object graph.

Comment: Database terminology is also new to me. I'll stick to the *persistent object graph* :-)